# Finding numbers with given GCD values

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was looking over the Eucledian algorithm for finding GCD of numbers. Now, it can be used to find GCD of two given numbers. However, if I am given GCD of a single number with multiple other numbers, for example, GCD of the first number with 3 other numbers (including itself), that is,

Given is: GCD of a with a, GCD of a with b, GCD of a with c, GCD of a with d. 
and same goes for the other numbers, i.e. GCD of b with a, b with b, .....

Then, how can I find the individual numbers? I know that GCD(a,a) = a itself but the problem here is, that the individual GCD given are in a random order, and therefore, I don't know which input number is the GCD of which two numbers. In that case, how do I find the individual numbers?

Here is my GCD code:

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
   if(b==0)
   {
       return a;
   }
   return gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

Example: Let's say the input given is,

```
3 1 3 1 4 2 2 3 6
3 //(total numbers we have to find in original array)
```

Then output should be, 3 4 6. Because if you calculate GCD pairwise (total 9 pairs and hence 9 numbers as input) of each of these numbers, then we get the output as above.

```
Explanation: 3 -> GCD of (3,3)
1 -> GCD of (3,4)
3 -> GCD of (3,6)
1 -> GCD of (4,3)
4 -> GCD of (4,4)
2 -> GCD of (4,6)
6 -> GCD of (6,6)
3 -> GCD of (6,3)
2 -> GCD of (6,4)
```

Therefore, I have to find the numbers whose GCD is given as input. Hence, (3,4,6) are those numbers.

Comment: Please provide an example of the inputs and what you expect to get as output.

Comment: could you explain your inputs? and what 9 pairs do you mean? which pair of numbers do you want to find gcd?

Comment: Look up the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with C++.

Comment: I guess it is too tough to do this. You know that, 1 + 4 = 5, and also 2 + 3 = 5, but that doesn't mean 1 = 2 or 3 = 4. What I mean to say is that GCD of two different pairs could come out to be the same, so it's difficult to find those numbers. I think a few restrictions could help, but still... an algorithm for this is tough to think of.

Comment: No, the thing is, I can output anyone of the combinations that is possible for this.

Comment: Does it need to be efficient for large inputs?  Could you do a brute force solution where you try successive numbers until you get a match?

Comment: @VaughnCato, what kind of a brute force solution are we looking at?

Comment: I think your output is the three largest numbers of your input. Check it for another input output sequence and let us know.

Comment: @vicky96, nope, I thought about it but it won't work. Take the example when array will come out to be (4,3,6,2). Here, 4 highest numbers in GCD array will be (6,4,3,3) and hence it's not the output. :)

Comment: i thought that gcd of same numbers would be provided as input

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this by the following process:

1. Find and remove largest number, this is one of the original numbers
2. Compute the gcd of the number just found in step 1, with all numbers previously found in step 1.
3. Remove each of these computed gcds from the input array of gcds (Strictly speaking remove 2 copies of each gcd)
4. Repeat until all numbers are found

The point is that this only goes wrong if the largest number x found in step 1 is not one of the original numbers.  However, this can only happen if x is a gcd of two other numbers.  These other numbers must be at least as large as x, but all such gcds have been removed in step 3.  Therefore x is always one of the original numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If the second line of the input is `1`, then the first line of the input will have only one number, and due to your observation that `gcd(a, a) = a`, the value of `a` will be whatever value is on the first line of input.

If the value on the second line of input is greater than 1, then the problem can be reduced using the following observation.  Given positive integers `a` and `b`, we know that `gcd(a, b) <= a = gcd(a, a)` and `gcd(a, b) <= b = gcd(b, b)` will always hold.  Therefore, we can conclude that the largest two numbers on the first line of input must both be part of the basic set of numbers.  The largest two numbers may be equal, but in your example, they are `4` and `6`, and they are not equal.

If there are more than two numbers to find, let's call the largest two `a` and `b`.  Since we now know the value of `a` and `b`, we can compute `gcd(a, b)` and remove two occurrences of that value from consideration as one of the input numbers.  We remove two occurrences because `gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a)` are both in the list of input numbers.  Then using similar logic, we conclude that the largest number remaining after `a`, `b`, `gcd(a, b)`, and `gcd(b, a)` are removed must be one of the input numbers.

Wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Very nice.  So this reduces to `while the input is not empty { Add the largest number in the input to your output; Remove new known gcd results from the input}`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy:

- count how many times each distinct number appears in the array
- if that count is odd, then that is one of the numbers in your set
- if that count is even, that is not one of the numbers in your set.

done.

This works because when x != y, gcd(x,y) = gcd(y,x) and that number will be in the array twice.  Only values that come from gcd(x,x) will be in the array once, leading to an odd number of that specific value.

Comment: This answer assumes that no number appears in the base set more than once.  If the base set is 3 3 2, then the first line of input would be something like 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 2, and this approach would find only that 2 is in the base set.

Comment: @EvanVanderZee Nice observation

Answer (score -1):

As we see here, that for each number with other number a GCD is calculated and added to the existing list, like this in the end we would be having n*n total numberer for original n numbers. So the same approach can be reverse used to find original numbers

1. Sort the list in descending order.
2. Collect top n^(0.5) numbers, that would be our answer.

For your example

> 3 1 3 1 4 2 2 3 6

Sorted = 6 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 1

value of n = 9

value of n^(0.5) = 3

choose top 3 numbers 6,4 and 3. Thats our answer

Comment: Well this isn't always true. Take this example :A = [46, 45, 40, 31, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]....  |A|^(0.5) = 5 so top 5 elements are [46,45,40,31,5] but actual answer should be : [46,45,40,31,1]